# Why executor memory used is shown greater than total available memory on spark web UI?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, spark-ui, spark-webui

I have a spark structured streaming job that is running for around last 3 weeks. When I open the Executors tab on spark web UI, it shows

```
 memory used - 36.1GB
 total available memory for storage - 3.2GB
```

For this application executor memory is set to 6GB.

Please refer to the below screenshot of Spark UI

[image: Spark UI Executors Memory]

I am not sure how should I interpret this information.

Comment: for Spark Explanation: `The Storage Memory column shows the amount of memory used and reserved for caching data.`  [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview/web-ui.html#executors-tab)   I was also confused why `used memory` greated than `reserved memory`